# Query to return the developers (DevID) who have not logged in for a month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Developers  Name                    LastLogin
Dev123456A  Paul Wilson             2013-04-10
Dev123456B  Actor One               2013-05-01
Dev123456C  Actor Two               2013-04-26
Dev123456D  Actor Three             2013-06-03
Dev123456E  Actor Four              2013-03-15
Dev123456F  Actor Five              2013-06-05
```

I have this Data.. I want to Select only the developers who have not logged in for a month.
I need the script to make it work.

I tried this:(THis one works) UPDATEd

```
SELECT  DevID, UserName, LastLogin
FROM    Developer
WHERE   LastLogin <= DateAdd(m,-1,GetDate())
```

Comment: I would like to see what script you have tried.  Think of this site as "help you do what you want and have tried" vs "do this for me" - we are really glad to assist with issues in code you have tried but fails.

Comment: What have you tried so far? As you will need a function to calculate the date, what database are you using?

Comment: By "have not logged in for a month" do you mean those not logged in in the month prior to today or those who have not logged in for a specific month?

Comment: not logged in in a month prior today

Comment: Is that "LastLogin" a datetime field or nvarchar or something else? - and is the DevID a unique primary key column? (are there duplicates for a given developer?)

Comment: @user2449983 Note that GETDATE() has a TIME part as well. It is best to strip the TIME part since you only keep track of dates without a time part in your database.

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of developers that haven't logged in for the last month, you should be able to use:

```
select DevID
from yt
group by developers
having max(lastlogin) < DateAdd(mm,-1,cast(GETDATE() as date));
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4b66/7)

If you want to know when the developers last logged in, then you could use a subquery:

```
select t.DevID, t.UserName, t.lastlogin
from yt t
inner join
(
  select DevID, max(lastlogin) lastlogin
  from yt
  group by DevID
  having max(lastlogin) < DateAdd(mm,-1,cast(GETDATE() as date))
) t2
  on t.DevID = t2.DevID
  and t.lastlogin = t2.lastlogin;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4b66/8)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you REALLY want is the first datetime of that months prior date (assumption that the LastLogin is a datetime column.

```
SELECT  DevID, UserName, LastLogin
FROM    Developer
WHERE   LastLogin < DATEADD(month,-1, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()))
```

SO for today, right now we would compare to '2013-05-06 00:00:00.000' as opposed to the exact time (right now) one month prior.  Thus any LastLogin on that date "counts" as opposed to those prior in time on that date actually being prior (in time but not date).

If you need exclusive of that date, you could add a day to the comparison date.

```
DATEADD(day, 1,DATEADD(month,-1, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE())))
```

returns '2013-05-07 00:00:00.000' "right now" so the less than works for that.